# HighCharts.StockChart tooltip lables on hover of datapoints is incorrect

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to add new points to chart in a progressive manner. After adding new points and setting new min/max, the tooltip labels are displayed incorrectly.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aAFLX/

```
$(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        },
        scrollbar:{
            enabled: true
        },
        lang: {
            rangeSelectorZoom: ' '
        }
    });

    var dataPoints = [[1293820200000, 45], [1293733800000, 25], [1293647400000, 65]]
    var counter = 0;

    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        rangeSelector: {
           enabled: false
        },
        navigator: {
          enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar : {
            enabled : false
        },        
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            linecolor: '#bbccdd',
            gridLineColor:'#bbccdd',
            tickInterval: 86400000,
            min: 1293820200000,
            max: 1294079400000
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Count',
            data : [[1293906600000, 56]],
            type : 'column',
        }]
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        if(counter == dataPoints.length) {
            return;
        }
        var point = dataPoints[counter++];
        var d = new Date(point[0]);
        var min = d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);

        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min,null);
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point);
    });
});
```

Any idea what is wrong? Am I missing something or using API incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Highstock does not do automatic sorting of the input data, so it must be sorted when given to Highstock. I think this is what is causing the problems.

So when adding new points, the added point must be later in time compared to the last one.

I have modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAFLX/3/) by sorting the datapoints:

```
dataPoints.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

and moving the first point back in time. (Also removed the call to setExtremes to keep all points in view, but that is not connected to the problem).

Comment: In my case, the data retrieved in batch and its in descending order. e.g. batch1 = [[2-Jan-2013, 25],[1-Jan-2013, 45]], batch2 = [[31-Dec-2012, 65],[30-Dec-2012, 7]]. Also I want render the chart as soon as I first batch, so that there is progressive rendering. As per your answer it seems like its not possible to achieve this without re-rendering the whole chart. Can you please suggest any better way or is there some library that supports such scenario?

Comment: Yes, if the data comes in unsorted you would need to re-render the chart. I'm afraid I don't know of any other solution